# JS filter to allow numbers with AND without dashes

Tags: javascript, filter, html-table

I need to filter a table that filters live while typing. It will use phone numbers, but needs to have the ability to accept numbers with and without dashes. 905-000-7777 and 9050007777 should both be acceptable when searching for that number.

This is what I have so far, I've been trying for hours:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Number search</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>905-000-7777</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>905-282-9992</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9050107777</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently I can have it filter the numbers but in the phone number, you must match the table variable perfectly. I'd like it to accept this OR that. I don't have much experience with js and this is proving to be more difficult then I thought.

Comment: In the comparison, remove dashes from both sides.

Comment: As ASDFGerte says, just remove the characters you want to ignore, so `filter = input.value.toUpperCase().replace(/-/g,'')` and `td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().replace(/-/g,'').indexOf(filter)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already explained in the comments, you can remove `-` hyphens from both input and cell contents before comparing. See the working fiddle below:

```
cleanedFilter = filter.replace("-","");

cellContent = td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().replace("-","");
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, cleanedFilter;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  
  cleanedFilter = filter.replace("-","");
  
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    
    if (td) {
      cellContent = td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().replace("-","");
    
      if (cellContent.indexOf(cleanedFilter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Number search</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>905-000-7777</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>905-282-9992</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9050107777</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, which will be something like that:

```
/^(\d+-?)+\d+$/
```